# Non-negative fat-tailed "almost stable" family of distribution with finite mean?

Tags: probability, kurtosis, sum, stable-distribution

I am looking for a *finite-dimensional* family of distributions $F_X(x)$ with all the following properties:

1. Supported on $[0, +\infty)$,
2. Fat tailed, i.e. $(1-F_X(x)) \sim x^{-\alpha}$ for $x\to +\infty$ and some $\alpha>0$,
3. The mean is finite (this implies $\alpha>1$ in 2.),
4. Stable under sum of i.i.d. variables: If $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim F_X$ are i.i.d., then $Y=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j$ belongs to the same family?

There are several examples if any of the conditions is removed:

1. The symmetric stable distributions with $\alpha>1$.
2. Many examples here: Gamma, Inverse Gaussian just to cite two.
3. The Levy distribution (and other one-sided stable distributions with $0<\alpha<1$.
4. Many examples here too: Pareto, Burr, Log-Gamma, etc.

Is there a family satisfying all of them, or is there a reason why it is impossible?

*Updated:* Clarify that the family has to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: I may not have been clear: if we drop condition 2 (fat tails) then Gamma is an example. In other words, Gamma satisfies 1, 3, and 4, but not 2.

Comment: You have fully described such a family!  The only thing one might need to show is that all distributions satisfying (1) - (3) also satisfy (4), but (3) implies the mean of the sum is finite; the sum clearly is positive (1); and since the sum stochastically dominates the minimum and the minimum is (trivially) fat-tailed, *QED.*

Comment: In fact I did, but that was not my intention! Let me reformulate: is there a finite dimensional sub-family , possibly with a nice parameterization?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#One-sided_stable_distribution_and_stable_count_distribution, the mean cannot be finite.

Comment: You could invent a family: for example the Gamma/Erlang distributions family can be seen as an extension of exponential distributions to include sums of $n$ iid copies of exponential distributions.  What is to stop you having a similar family of sums of $n$  iid Pareto distributions?

Comment: @whuber the statement in the wiki refers to the _stable_ family, which is closed under arbitrary linear combinations of iid variables. My condition 4. has simple sums only.

Comment: When you allow a scale parameter, there's no difference.